# How to initiate the contents of a subclassed UserList in Python

Tags: python

This works:

```
class customList(list):
    def __init__(self, liste):
        list.__init__(self, liste)
myList = customList([4])
```

This does not:

```
from collections import UserList

class customList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, liste):
        list.__init__(self, liste)
myList = customList([4])
```

I have read subclassing `UserList` is preferred over subclassing the build-in `list`, because of unknown behavior of the latter, but how should I initiate the list in my `__init__` when subclassing from `UserList`?

Comment: what about `UserList.__init__(self, liste)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `UserList`'s constructor to initialize it, instead of `list`'s constructor:

```
class customList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, liste):
        super().__init__(liste)
```

Comment: I should have learned some more about how Python handles inheritance. I was a bit unaware of super(). Thanks.

Comment: Do note that if all you're going to do in the constructor is call `UserList`s constructor, then you don't need to define `__init__` it at all as `UserList`s will be called by default.

Comment: @Turksarama Agree. But here I assume OP wants to do some additional work in constructor, which are not shown in the posted code. In this case, `super()` must be called.

Answer (score 2):

A UserList is a wrapper around its internal `data` parameter.

```
from collections import UserList

class customList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, liste):
        self.data = liste
myList = customList([4])

print(myList) # [4]
myList.append(5)
print(myList) # [4, 5]
```

The main reason you might want to use a UserList rather than a list as your base class is to access the underlying list as an attribute, which is only really important if you wanted to reassign it for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about the data attribute, really usefull.